# Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback nor receive function

Tags: hardhat, testing, chai

I'm getting a console error in hardhat test case
this is my solidity code

```
/**
 * donateToCampaign - Allows a user to donate to a specific campaign.
 *
 * @param _id the ID of the campaign to donate to.
 */
function donateToCampaign(uint256 _id) public payable noReentrancy {
    uint256 amount = msg.value;

    Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

    require(
        campaign.status != CampaignStatus.Close,
        "This campaign is not open to fund."
    );

    require(
        campaign.deadline > block.timestamp &&
            isCampaignOpen(campaign.status),
        "The campaign is not open or has reached its goal."
    );

    require(
        campaign.amountCollected + amount <= campaign.target,
        "Donation exceeds campaign target."
    );

    campaign.amountCollected += amount;
    campaign.donators.push(payable(msg.sender));
    campaign.donations.push(amount);

    if (campaign.amountCollected == campaign.target) {
        campaign.status = CampaignStatus.Successful;
        emit CampaginSuccessfullyFunded(campaign);
    }

    payable(address(this)).transfer(amount);
}
```

and the test case in hardhat using chai

```
 it("should allow a user to donate to a campaign", async () => {
const target = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
await contract.connect(aliceAccount).createCampaign(
  "Test Campaign",
  "Test Description",
  target,
  "testimage.jpg"
);
let cc = await contract.campaigns(0);
const tx = await contract
  .connect(bobAccount)
  .donateToCampaign(0, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5") });
const campaign = await contract.campaigns(0);
expect(campaign.amountCollected).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5"));
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to `transfer` the value if the value is sent in a payable method
No need:
 `payable(address(this)).transfer(amount)`

If you really want to use this then you have to define a fallback function to receive ether.

Eg.

```
........
receive() payable external {}
........
```

Fallback function is necessary to receive any amount of ether. Otherwise you can not send ether to the smart contract using wallet like metamask.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error comes from the last line of your function.

> payable(address(this)).transfer(amount); // Also why tf are you doing that?

Here, your contract  is trying to call its  own fallback ( or receive) function, if it doesnt exist, the whole call would revert with this error message.

Also, unrelated, but why are you using a nonReentrant modifier inside a function that doesn't make any external calls?